# Python lxml cannot get all text

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I am using Python `lxml` library for parsing HTML.
I have got leaf point such as `<a>` and want to get its parent’s text.
I tried doing it in two ways:

1. `.xpath('::parent*')`,
2. `.getparent().text`.

```py
from lxml.etree import HTML
text = '<p>FIRST PART<a href="THE LINK" target="_blank">LINK TEXT</a>SECOND PART</p>'

parsed = HTML(text)
parsed.xpath('//a')[0].getparent().text
parsed.xpath('//a/parent::*')[0].text
```

I got `FIRST PART` using either approach, but how can I obtain the `SECOND PART`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.itertext()`](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html?highlight=getparent#lxml.etree._Element.itertext) method of an Element:

```
from lxml.etree import HTML

text = '<p>FIRST PART<a href="THE LINK" target="_blank">LINK TEXT</a>SECOND PART</p>'
parsed = HTML(text)

parent = parsed.xpath('//a/parent::*')[0]
text = list(parent.itertext())
print(text[0])
print(text[-1])
```

Prints:

```
FIRST PART
SECOND PART
```